# MongoDb - Give user access to specific database

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on an application using different databases and struggling to implement the correct user management.

Suppose that we have a user "BasicUser" (created in the admin database), that only has dbAdmin rights to a specific database, called "TestDb" in this example. Furthermore, we have created a user "TestUser" without any access rights to start from.

Is there a possibility for the BasicUser to grant read/write access to the TestDb for the TestUser?

I tried the following options when I login with the BasicUser

- use TestDb; db.grantRolesToUser("TestUser", ["read"]) --> This returns an error that the user cannot be found
- use TestDb; db.updateUser("TestUser", {roles: ["read"]}) --> This returns an error that we are not autorized to execute the command

To be clear, I do not want to provide the BasicUser any admin rights on the admin database, as I don't want the BasicUser to see any of the other databases. This user should only be able to see the TestDb and perform its admin tasks on this db.

Comment: I was having the same issue. In version 3.4 the docs [https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/#required-access](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/#required-access) state 'You must have the **grantRole** action on a database to grant a role on that database.' If you are in an environment such as OpenShift (where db users likely do not have those privileges), then assigning user privs might not be an option. My OpenShift cluster only allows one database user per database and only one database per Db service (specified at db creation).

Answer (score 2):

Create the user in the `admin` database (actually I don't know any reason why a user might be created anywhere else).

Then grant

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").grantRolesToUser( "TestUser", [ { role: "dbOwner", db: "TestDb" } ] )
```

It's not clear what you mean by "give access"? Maybe instead of `dbOwner`, you just want to grant `readWrite`, see [Built-In Roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/index.html)