# Mongodb Atlas to give database/project access to another login user

Tags: mongodb, project, user-accounts

Unlike [MongoDb - Give user access to specific database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65189390/mongodb-give-user-access-to-specific-database), I'm not talking about user created in the Mongodb database, but Mongodb Atlas login user.

So,

- I login into Mongodb Atlas with my own account
- I created a Mongodb database, and I believe only me can access it

What I want is to give access to such database to my friend, to his own Mongodb Atlas login account.

Yet all the search hits I found are talking about creating a user in the Mongodb database then give database access to it.

Comment: You want the other person to be able to log in to the Atlas UI or connect to the database?

Comment: The other person can log in to the Atlas UI himself, I just want him to connect/access to my database in Atlas UI, @user20042973.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/access/manage-project-access/#add-users-or-teams-to-a-project

Comment: BINGO! Thanks a lot!